# Driving a speaker with a 3.3 V processor

Tags: microcontroller, gpio

I got this design off of the internet and it is not working.   I am trying to drive a  PKLCS1212E4001-R1 with a MMBT2222A-7-F.   The 3.3 V of the STM32L0 is not enough to turn on the BJT transistor.   The package of the MMBT2222A is an SOT 23-3.  Is there a part substitution that will work with this PCB footprint?
[image]

Comment: 3.3V from MCU should be more than enough to drive the transistor base with enough current. Either the block diagram is so simplified it does not show all components, or there is no base resistor, or the MCU pin is incorrectly configure so it's not controlling the transistor properly.

Comment: That volume control could well be the problem. And you need a resistor between ALARM and Q1 base : 1 kilohm would be fine.

Comment: You can't drive a piezo sounder like that - if it really is a piezo sounder. That will work with an electromagnetic sounder. You could drive a piezo one straight from a digital output although a buffer would be preferable.

Comment: did you connect the ground between the microprocessor and the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

The open-collector transistor amplifier you've drawn is appropriate (if it had a base resistor and an audio-taper pot) for a small magnetic speaker with a coil, which is a current-mode device.

Your piezoelectric transducer is more of a voltage-mode device; essentially it can be thought of as "a capacitor which makes noise when its level of charge is rapidly *changed*".

The problem with your circuit is that you can only charge the capacitor, not discharge it.  And once you apply the charge, it would take a long time for it to leak away, so you'll get at most a single click from this.

One simple fix would be to add a resistor across the capacitor; in fact that's precisely one of the circuits you'll find on a data sheet.  The transistor applies charge, the resistor drains it away, so now you can get the charge to change and noise to be made.

You actually may not need the transistor at all though: for moderate volume applications you can likely drive one side of small to moderate size piezo right from an MCU pin.   You  could even double the applied voltage by driving the other side from another pin controlled with opposite phase (though no, that won't make the sound twice as loud).

As an interesting anecdote, the audio generators in the "snap circuits" toy also have unipolar output drive, and are meant to be used with a magnetic speaker connected between that and one of the supply rails (I forget which, but given the unipolar drive, only one way will work).   The toy also happens to contain a piezo element, which the audio generators seemingly  will not drive.  But if you then add the filament lightbulb or the resistor elements across the piezo, *now you get sound*.  It's either the identical issue as in your circuit, or the inverted image.

Answer (score 1):

This answer includes a schematic with problems pointed out by @ChrisStratton and in comments corrected, though the end result is not the final word on this design. I am using the parts in the original schematic, but it is possible a 8 ohm or 16 ohm speaker may have a louder, more clear output.

9 volts powers just the speaker and Q1. R3 acts to quickly discharge the speaker so it is ready for the next pulse. ALARM input is routed through the volume control to the base of Q1. R2 prevents the base from shorting the ALARM signal to ground if R1 is cranked to full volume. C1 was increased to 10 uF to absorb audio frequency currents, thus the small load should not interact with the 9 volt supply.

Based on the given values 12 volts is a safe "high" value. R3 could be replaced with a 1 mH inductor, but this would increase the voltage peaks on the piezo speaker. Also ignored for now is a series capacitor for the speaker, whether it is piezo or coil type. This removes DC offsets from the speaker, but mostly this is an issue if Q1 became stuck in an "ON" state.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Rfwb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Dont you need a DC- blocking capacitor just before the Speaker?